# Why does this keep on happening python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
user_grade=0
users_name=input("What is your name \n")
import random

count=1
while count<=10:
  ops = ["+" , "-", "*", "/"]
  num1 = random.randint(0,50)
  num2 = random.randint(0,20)
  operation = random.choice(ops)


  math=(num1, operation, num2)
  user_answer=int(input("What is " + str(math) + "\n"))
  if user_answer==num1 + num2:
    print("Correct answer")
    user_grade+=1

  if user_answer==num1 - num2:
    print("Correct answer")
    user_grade+=1

  if user_answer==num1 * num2:
    print("Correct answer")
    user_grade+=1

  if user_answer==num1 / num2:
    print("Correct answer")
    user_grade+=1
  else:
    print("incorrect or invalid")
  count+=1

print("You got ", user_grade ,"/10")
```

this the output:

```
What is your name 
Ibad
What is (39, '*', 2)
78
Correct answer
incorrect or invalid
```

why does the incorrect part keep on repeating

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `if` when you're supposed to be using `elif`. `elif` creates a block of statements, exiting upon the first match or `True`. Using separate `if` statements will check *all* of the conditions, which will lead to error even when there is none.

```py
user_grade=0
users_name=input("What is your name \n")
import random

count=1
while count<=10:
  ops = ["+" , "-", "*", "/"]
  num1 = random.randint(0,50)
  num2 = random.randint(0,20)
  operation = random.choice(ops)


  math=(num1, operation, num2)
  user_answer=int(input("What is " + str(math) + "\n"))
  if user_answer==num1 + num2:
    print("Correct answer")
    user_grade+=1

  elif user_answer==num1 - num2:
    print("Correct answer")
    user_grade+=1

  elif user_answer==num1 * num2:
    print("Correct answer")
    user_grade+=1

  elif user_answer==num1 / num2:
    print("Correct answer")
    user_grade+=1
  else:
    print("incorrect or invalid")
  count+=1

print("You got ", user_grade ,"/10")
```

Answer (score 0):

use or operator instead of that many if's

```
if((user_answer==num1 + num2) or (user_answer==num1 - num2) or (user_answer==num1 * num2) or (user_answer==num1 / num2)):
   user_grade+=1
else:
   print('Incorrect or invalid)
```